# Using SQL SUM with Case statement containing inner SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, an `Orders` table which contains a list of a users orders and a `OrderShippingCosts` table which contains a price for shipping each item based on the `OrderTypeID` in the `Orders` table.

I am running a query like below to calculate the total shipping costs:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN OR.OrderTypeID = 1 
              THEN (SELECT CostOfShippingSmallParcel 
                    FROM OrderShippingCosts) 
              ELSE (SELECT CostOfShippingBigParcel 
                    FROM OrderShippingCosts) 
        END) AS TotalShippingCost
FROM 
    Orders AS OR
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Does anyone know what is wrong with my query?

Comment: Well, you can't have aggregates (other sums, maxs, mins, etc) or subqueries (e.g. select statements) inside an aggregate function... You would be better off rewriting your query with a join or an apply.

Comment: Don't use `OR` as alias name. If really want to use that use with square bracket `[OR]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810(v=sql.110).aspx) takes an *expression* on input, which evaluates into single data value, not a dataset. [*Expression*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286(v=sql.110).aspx) definition from MSDN:

> Is a combination of symbols and operators that the SQL Server Database Engine evaluates to obtain a **single data value**.

You trying to pass to `SUM` function a dataset (which is result of subquery), not a single data value. This is simplification of what you trying to query:

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT Number FROM SomeTable)
```

It is not valid. The valid query would be:

```
SELECT SUM(Value) FROM SomeTable
```

In your particular case looks like you missing `JOIN`. Your original logic will result in summary of entire `OrderShippingCosts` table for each row of `Orders` table. I think, it should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM
    (
        CASE
            WHEN ord.OrderTypeID = 1 THEN ship.CostOfShippingSmallParcel 
            ELSE ship.CostOfShippingBigParcel 
        END
    ) TotalShippingCost
FROM Orders AS ord
JOIN OrderShippingCosts ship ON /* your search condition, e.g.: ord.OrderID = ship.OrderID */
```

By the way, it is not a good idea to use reserved symbols as aliases, names and so on. In your query you use `OR` as alias for `Orders` table. Symbol `OR` is reserved for logical [`or`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx) operation. If you really need to use reserved symbol, wrap it into `[` and `]` square  braces. Look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.105).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: And Cant use that `Subquery returned more than 1 value` in `then clause`

Comment: It looks like my answer now.

Comment: It looks like my answer after your editing. But its not problem for me. Just want to say.

Comment: @Hebele I haven't seen you answer. We answered similar in same time just because answer seems obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is clear, you can avoid it with a join:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN [OR].OrderTypeID = 1 
             THEN CostOfShippingSmallParcel  
             ELSE CostOfShippingBigParcel END) AS   TotalShippingCost
FROM Orders [OR]
CROSS JOIN OrderShippingCosts
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this...

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN OR.OrderTypeID = 1 
    THEN (SELECT SUM(CostOfShippingSmallParcel) FROM OrderShippingCosts) 
    ELSE (SELECT SUM(CostOfShippingBigParcel) FROM OrderShippingCosts) END AS   TotalShippingCost
FROM Orders AS OR
```

Let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    ISNULL
    (
        SUM
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN O.OrderTypeID = 1 THEN C.CostOfShippingSmallParcel
                ELSE C.CostOfShippingBigParcel END
        ), 0
    ) AS TotalShippingCost
FROM 
    Orders AS O LEFT JOIN 
    OrderShippingCosts C ON O.Id = C.OrderId -- Your releation id
```

Comment: `ISNULL` call is useless because `sum` ignores `null` values. The only case, where this kind of call would be usefull is when you return data from function or stored proc. But in this case expression need to be changed to `ISNULL(SUM(column))`. In that case in resulted dataset column will be always treated as not nullable, same as when you define `not null` column in table definition. For example, this may be a hint for ORMs to generate not nullable class member for type, mapped on returned dataset.

Comment: You are right. But I think `IsNull` is required. If there is no data in OrderShippingCosts  table `SUM` will return `NULL` Answer is updated.

Comment: If there is no data you will result in empty dataset, no any rows at all. However `isnull` would be useful with `left join` - that's right.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum (or.TotalShippingCost)
FROM
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN OR.OrderTypeID = 1 
    THEN (SELECT CostOfShippingSmallParcel FROM OrderShippingCosts) 
    ELSE (SELECT CostOfShippingBigParcel FROM OrderShippingCosts) END) AS   TotalShippingCost
FROM Orders AS OR
```

Comment: This query cant work. You cant use like `THEN (SELECT CostOfShippingSmallParcel FROM OrderShippingCosts) ` You can `THEN (SELECT top 1 CostOfShippingSmallParcel FROM OrderShippingCosts) `

Comment: are you saying 'cant work' or 'might not work'?  I believe it will work if the cost of shipping tables have single rows in them - otherwise what is the intention supposed to be?  You could change to SELECT SUM(CostOfShippingSmallParcel) FROM OrderShippingCosts - or some other single row selection strategy (even TOP 1)

Comment: You will get an error. `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: no I've just run a query just like it, as long as the inner select returns a single record, it will run (that's the next thing for the questioner to consider, if appropriate) - note there is no info on how the record from OrderShippingCosts is selected or joined to

Comment: consider for example select sum(ord.TotalShippingCost) from 
(SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 
    THEN (SELECT 1 ) 
    ELSE (SELECT  2) END AS   TotalShippingCost
FROM addressdetails)  AS ORD

Comment: but i agree you get your error with select sum(ord.TotalShippingCost) from 
(SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 
    THEN (SELECT 1 union select 26) 
    ELSE (SELECT  2) END AS   TotalShippingCost
FROM addressdetails)  AS ORD

Comment: If table has one row. There is no problem. But its bad idea.

Comment: that's fair enough!  I've seen it go wrong for those reasons yes.