# Pivot in SQL in multiarray variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pivot

I’ve got this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EURO` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Flow` tinytext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the data are like this:

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`ID`, `EURO`, `Date`, `Flow`) VALUES
(1, '25.34', '2017-05-03', 'Income'),
(2, '48.49', '2017-07-12', 'Income'),
(3, '33.45', '2016-07-02', 'Income'),
(4, '21.23', '2016-02-03', 'Income'),
(5, '14.45', '2016-01-03', 'Outcome'),
(6, '11.45', '2017-03-03', 'Outcome'),
(7, '18.21', '2017-06-03', 'Outcome');
```

And I’d like to get this result:

```
Flow     2016                        2017
--------------------------------------------------------------
Income   SUM of Income_EURO @ 2016   SUM of Income_EURO @ 2017    
Outcome  SUM of Outcome_EURO @ 2016  SUM of Outcome_EURO @ 2017
```

I have looked through some of the articles about Pivot in SQL and I tried this query:

```
SELECT Flow, 
    SUM(EURO
        CASE(WHILE YEAR(Date) = '2016'
             AS 2016),
    SUM(EURO
        CASE(WHILE YEAR(Date) = '2017'
             AS 2017)
    FROM test_table
GROUP BY Flow;
```

But I got this error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE(WHILE YEAR(Date) = '2016'
             AS 2016),
    SUM(EURO
        CA' at line 3.
```

I believe something is wrong with syntax.
Would you please suggest me what’s wrong or suggest your approach?

**And second question about multiarray variable in php**

I have got this php code:

```
<?php

$my_var = array(
  array('ID' => '1','EURO' => '25.34','Date' => '2017-05-03','Flow' => 'Income'),
  array('ID' => '2','EURO' => '48.49','Date' => '2017-07-12','Flow' => 'Income'),
  array('ID' => '3','EURO' => '33.45','Date' => '2016-07-02','Flow' => 'Income'),
  array('ID' => '4','EURO' => '21.23','Date' => '2016-02-03','Flow' => 'Income'),
  array('ID' => '5','EURO' => '14.45','Date' => '2016-01-03','Flow' => 'Outcome'),
  array('ID' => '6','EURO' => '11.45','Date' => '2017-03-03','Flow' => 'Outcome'),
  array('ID' => '7','EURO' => '18.21','Date' => '2017-06-03','Flow' => 'Outcome')
);

foreach(@my_var as @var){
echo $var, '<br />;
}

echo $my_var[0][0].;

?>
```

Neither of both echo work in this example.
Would you please help me with syntax.
I am using phpmyadmin version 4.6.5.2., php version 5.6.30. and MariaDB SQL server.

Thank you!

Comment: on your second question, you cannot echo on an array. but you can use `print_r($var);` for arrays.

Comment: try my solution it will help you

Comment: If you have access to PHP, then it really makes little sense to use a pivot.

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, but I do not know yet how to make pivot in PHP. Just learning.. But thanks for advice! I made this pivot in Excel with no problem, now tried SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below Query Tested.
Read some useful about sum from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350150/using-sql-sum-with-case-statement-containing-inner-select)

```
SELECT Flow,
SUM(CASE WHEN year(Date) = 2016 THEN euro ELSE 0 END) As SUM2016, 
SUM(CASE WHEN year(Date) = 2017 THEN euro ELSE 0 END) As SUM2017
FROM test_table GROUP BY Flow
```

For second issue replace @ with $

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, this query works! Any ideas how to modify the same query to calculate difference grouped by year? E.g. Income - Outcome and grouped by year? And of course @ should be replaced by $! I somehow didn't see it..

Answer (score 0):

- **First Issue** - Your alias is at wrong place in the SQL. Try using below code

  ```
  SELECT Flow, 
  SUM(EURO
          CASE(WHILE YEAR(Date) = '2016') AS 2016,
  SUM(EURO
         CASE(WHILE YEAR(Date) = '2017') AS 2017
  FROM test_table
  GROUP BY Flow;
  ```
- **Second Issue** - You can't use variables with @. $ needs to be used instead.

  ```
  foreach($my_var as $var){
      print_r($var);
      echo '<br />;
  }
  ```

Below code will not work, as your array is an associative array. Thus you need to use the named array keys for accessing the data.

```
    echo $my_var[0][0].;
```

For example if you want to access ID of first row, then below code will be used -

```
     echo $my_var[0]['ID'];
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek for help. Code you supplied do not work, but I got code from Ahmed above and it works: 
`SELECT Flow, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN year(Date) = 2016 THEN euro ELSE 0 END)
       As SUM2016, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN year(Date) = 2017 THEN euro ELSE 0 END)
       As SUM2017
   FROM test_table 
GROUP BY Flow`. 

And thanks for PHP help. It works!